# php short syntax understanding ($z++ % 2) ? "a" : "b";

Tags: php

Newbie here, and i don't know what means `($z++ % 2) ? "a" : "b";` in php and this code gives me the next warning in an old code

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in

Comment: There is this secret resource called [**The Manual**](http://php.net/docs.php) Only very special developers are allowed to use it. You need an inviation to be allowed to read it. _Consider this you personal invitation_ it is written in many languages

Comment: *"and i don't know what means ($z++ % 2) ? "a" : "b";"* - modulus/ternary

Comment: *"A non-numeric value encountered"* - `a/b` are not numeric (obviously), they're strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
$z = 5;
echo ($z++ % 2) ? "a" : "b";
```

(5%2) = 1 = true

=> a printed

then z became 6

Answer (score 2):

1. `$z++` means increase value of `$z` after use
2. `$z++ % 2` means give me a remainder of `$z/2`, and increase `$z` after
3. If `$z%2 == 0`, you get `b`, if `$z%2 == 1`, you get `a`

Warning shows because `$z` is undeclared before. Please add before your code this line:

```
$z = 0;
```

Comment: ty this helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

This code evaluates to "a" when $z is odd and "b" when $z is even and then increments $z by one.

`$z++` increments $z by one, but only AFTER using it in the expression (note that the PHP manual states that the order of evaluation is undefined and therefore could change between versions. See [example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).)

`% 2` modulo 2 (will be 1 if odd, 0 if even)

`? :` is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

When $z is odd `($z++ % 2) == 1` which evaluates to true and the result will be "a".

When $z is even `($z++ % 2) == 0` which evaluates to false and the result will be "b".

The warning is probably because $z is undeclared or not a number (e.g. a string) when this code executes. The % and ++ operators are only valid for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`($z++ % 2) ? "a" : "b";` this is the shorthand version of If/Else (: and ? call as Ternary Operators )it works like this

```
if($z++ % 2){
  "a"
}
else{
  "b"
}
```

1. `$z++` increment the existing value of $z from 1
2. `%` gives the remain value after it divide from 2.
3. If the argument (`$z++ % 2`) gives any value It executes If("a").
4. It executes else part("b") if it gives 0.

Example 1:

`$z=10;`

`($z++ % 2)`

`(5+1 % 2)`

`(6 % 2)`

`(0)`

result is 0 then do b

Read this for more information: [link](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) [operators](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)
Happy Coding :)